# fscanf not scanning input correctly?

Tags: c

fscanf doesn't seem to be reading in values. Any idea why? The input file is poly.dat, and it has several rows corresponding to (x, y) pairs; see below. I check the output value of fscanf, but I don't remember if there's a better way. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

poly.dat:

```
2
0.0 0.0
1.0 0.0
0.75 0.4330127018922193
0.25 0.4330127018922193
0.0 0.0
0.25 0.4330127018922193
0.75 0.4330127018922193
0.5 0.8660254037844386
0.25 0.4330127018922193
```

invocation:

% ./program poly.dat poly-converted.dat

source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if (argc != 3 ) {
        printf("usage: %s <input> <output>\n", 
                argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    FILE *fo = fopen(argv[2], "w");

    int N = 0; /* How many tiers? */
    double x=0.0, y=0.0; 
    const double MARGIN = 0.10; 

    fscanf(fp, "%d", &N);
    fprintf(fo, "%d\n", N);

    while ( fscanf(fp, "%f %f", &x, &y) == 2) {
        double xprime = x + MARGIN; 
        double yprime = MARGIN + 1.0 - y; 

        fprintf(fo, "%f %f\n", xprime, yprime);

    }

    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fo);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Which `fscanf` fails? You should check the `fopen()` calls didn't return null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `fscanf` with a pointer to `double`, you need to use `%lf` instead of `%f`. Otherwise, you are going to get wrong results in your `x` and `y` variables.

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/Dp1Ctq)

Answer (score 1):

Don't ever use fscanf; when it fails it is very hard to know how much input has been consumed.

fgets and sscanf make for a much more debuggable separation of concerns.